# Remove localStorage data on app uninstall

Tags: electron, local-storage, electron-builder

I have created an electron app and built it using [electron-builder](https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder)
On app uninstall I need to delete the data that localStorage includes, like JWT tokens and other user-specific data.

Currently the issue I am facing is when the app is uninstalled when the use is logged in, and the user re-installs the app, the login and some other user data persists which I want to prevent.

I tried searching for an `uninstall` event that we could get but couldn't find any.

I do not want to clear that data when the app has auto-updated.
Is there any event I could capture an event in electron or use any other bundler that could clear localStorage on uninstall?

Comment: Have you tried this on nsis json, "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true?

Comment: @MicSel app "deleteAppDataOnUninstall": true doesn't work on Mac OS

Comment: Hi @Ryan I am also facing this problem have you found the solution?